# Minimizing L-infinity norm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, linear-programming

I have this MATLAB code and I´m trying to implement the method explained in top answer of this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12546/software-package-to-solve-l-infinity-norm-linear-regression
Here is the code that I´m using that starts with the data points:

```
x = [
    0
    0.101010101010101
    0.202020202020202
    0.303030303030303
    0.404040404040404
    0.505050505050505
    0.606060606060606
    0.707070707070707
    0.808080808080808
    0.909090909090909
    ];
y = [
    0.052993311292562
    14.923120014175920
    1.974502763975613
    -2.205773310050583
    -0.052548781318830
    2.935428041987883
    0.134606520161892
    0.146742215922384
    -0.418386565682831
    1.702041272689124
    ];
A1 = [x,ones(length(y),1),-ones(length(y),1)];
A2 = [-x,-ones(length(y),1),-ones(length(y),1)];
A = [A1;A2];
f = [0;0;1];
linprog(f,A,[y;-y])
```

The point is to find the the parameters (slope and intersection) of the best fit, i.e. a line, by minimizing the **L-infinity norm** of the residuals between the line and data points. I have made the same problem work for **ordinary least squares** (minimizing the L-2 norm) as well as for the **L-1 fit**. The line plotted from those methods fit really nicely between the data points. But can't seem to make this L-infinity fit work no matter what I do so I come to you for help, any tips appreciated.

Comment: I think your second ones vectors should be negative in both A1 and A2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sign of *t* in your inequalities is wrong. Try

```
A1 = [x,ones(length(y),1),-ones(length(y),1)];
A2 = [-x,-ones(length(y),1),-ones(length(y),1)];
```

Comment: Yes I had already tried that combination of signs and the solution (slope: -7.45 intersection:7.86) is so far from the least squares solution (slope: 0.26 intersection:0.55) and the L1 solution (slope: 0.13 intersection:0.05), which are consistent with each other I think. Is that maybe the point of L-Infinty, it gives extra weight to extreme points or something?

Comment: The least squares solution gives much more weight to the outliers (the residual is squared), so here the solution will be pulled in the direction of that one big outlier, but it's still kept in check by the other 9 data points. The infinity norm solution is always midway between the smallest (negative) and largest (positive) residual, and the other data points don't matter. So in that sense the extreme points do have more weight.